# Cannot make std::unique_ptr<std::istream> hold a pointer to std::ifstream

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, istream

Consider the following piece of code (out of context for the sake of simplicity):

```
std::unique_ptr<std::istream> stream;
stream = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

This code compiles just fine with MSVC and works with no problem, but Clang issues an error:

```
error: no viable overloaded '='
stream = std::make_unique<std::ifstream>(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

Alongside with the error above, the log also claims that `'unique_ptr<std::basic_ifstream<char>, default_delete<std::basic_ifstream<char>>>'` is not convertable to `'unique_ptr<std::istream, default_delete<std::istream>>'`.

I cannot use a reference as I need to keep `stream` alive outside the current scope, so a pointer seems to be the only solution. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Not saying it's not a problem but any reason why you declare it as `unique_ptr<std::istream>` instead of `unique_ptr<std::ifstream>` -- since that is, in fact, what you are creating?  Do you need to then pass this pointer to code that expects the generic type?

Comment: Worked for me with my clang++ compiler, after I added the missing stuff to make it compile and run.

Comment: @Joe the question is not about whether I should use a pointer in another way or not, but since you're asking, `stream` is not just an object on its own, it is a field of a class and must support not only `ifstream` but `stringstream` as well because the class itself is used in several contexts

Comment: @Kaiyakha which compiler version are you using? it works for me using both g++ 9.4 and clang++ 10.

Comment: Can't reproduce with either libc++ or libstdc++ on current upstream Clang (https://godbolt.org/z/vrbjq9Tf4).

Comment: @Kaiyakha, I figured that when I asked the question.  I was asking because if the problem were actually some weird bug with CLANG, that might have been a workaround

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
int maint() {
    // block
    {
        uint8_t buffer_size = 128;
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer(new char[buffer_size]);
        memset(buffer.get(), 0, buffer_size);
        //// register unique_ptr to handle resource
        std::unique_ptr<std::ifstream, void(*)(std::ifstream *)>
                f(new std::ifstream(FILE_PATH, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary), [](std::ifstream *f) {
                    f->close(); // custom deleter
                });
        if (!f->is_open()) {
            return 0;
        }
        while (!f->eof()) {
            f->read(buffer.get(), buffer_size);
            std::cout << buffer.get() << std::endl;
        }
    } // trigger deleter to free resource
}
```

Comment: This looks like code right out of an AI. No explanation, no nothing, what's the point?

Comment: just give it try.